# NiFi Registry 0.8.0 unable to load cache item error

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I download NiFi Registry 0.8.0 version and ran **run-nifi-registry.bat** file but it gives the below error, any suggestions? All settings are default

JDK: 14
OS: Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a much better time running it under Linux - notice that Windows is not listed as a supported OS http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/getting-started.html#downloading-and-installing-nifi-registry

> NiFi Registry can be downloaded from the NiFi Registry Page. There are two packaging options available: a tarball and a zip file. Supported operating systems include Linux, Unix and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same error with  nifi registry v1.17.0.
Was able to get nifi registry v1.17.0 working on my windows 10 machine.

**Solution**: use JDK8 on windows.
I installed AdoptOpenJDK 8 and configured it in JAVA_HOME environment variable.
For some reason if I set JAVA_HOME in windows terminal it was not picking up.
Had to explicitly add it via Control panel -> System properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables.

FYI: the error I saw in nifi registry logs when using java 11 was:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create JAXBContext.
at org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.StandardProviderFactory.initializeJaxbContext(StandardProviderFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.StandardProviderFactory.(StandardProviderFactory.java:64)
... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.